# Is it possible to control the mouse cursor using keyboard in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, keycode

Please advise me if it is possible to control the mouse cursor using the keyboard in ActionScript 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible.

The closet you can get is 'faking' events that would typically be dispatched by Mouse input, e.g.

```
dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK) );
```

You can also [hide the cursor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html#hide%28%29) and create your own DisplayObject to represent its position.

Comment: + 1 for suggesting to create a custom pointer, though it wouldn't be where the actual mouse location is once code based control takes over.  Also a good point to note is many browsers prevent a non-user initiated click event, ie, a faked click.

Comment: @Ribs They don't prevent a fake click event - they just prevent a lot of actions that should only be click initiated like going full screen.